# Why is this PHP include not working?

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to create a logout link that gets included into an authorized area.

The authorized area looks like this:

```
<?php require_once '../../includes/initialize.php';
if(!$Session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to('login.php'); }

$user = $User->find_by_id($Session->user_id);

?>


<!-------------- START OF LOGOUT LINK -------------->


<?php
if (isset($_GET['logout']))
{
    $Session->logout($user);
    $Logger->logout($user);
    redirect_to('login.php');
}
?>

<p style="float: right;"><a href="?logout=true">Logout</a></p>


<!-------------- END OF LOGOUT LINK -------------->


<p>Welcome <?php echo $user->first_name; ?>, you are now logged into the admin area.</p>
```

**The above code works just fine!**

But when I change it so the logout link is an include, I get an error.  This is what I put in my include file called logoutlink.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['logout']))
{
    $Session->logout($user);
    $Logger->logout($user);
    redirect_to('login.php');
}
?>

<p style="float: right;"><a href="?logout=true">Logout</a></p>
```

I then include it into my authorized area as such:

```
<?php require_once '../../includes/initialize.php';
if(!$Session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to('login.php'); }

$user = $User->find_by_id($Session->user_id);

?>


<!-------------- START OF LOGOUT LINK -------------->


<?php include '../../includes/logoutlink.php'; ?>


<!-------------- END OF LOGOUT LINK -------------->


<p>Welcome <?php echo $user->first_name; ?>, you are now logged into the admin area.</p>
```

I get the following errors:

**Notice: Undefined variable: Session...**

&

**Fatal error: Call to a member function logout() on a non-object in...**

Can someone explain what I'm missing?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Which lines are you getting the errors in?

Comment: It's complaining about $Session->logout($user); but as I mentioned, if I don't use an include, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `global $Session;` at the top of you `logoutlink.php` file.

Comment: That did the trick! Would you mind refreshing my understand of why the $Session was considered local to this include file?

Comment: My educated guess, `$Session` was instantiated in `initialize.php`, which is "included". I guess variables cannot start in an included file, span across the parent file, then into another included file. I'm guessing if you include `global $Session;` into the parent file, it should work as well. Here's more on PHP variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Excellent! This helps a lot. Thank you.  I'm analogizing the included logoutlink.php file to a function, where everything within it is local. Would that be a fair way to think?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are using $Session, and not $_Session.

If $Session is a user defined variable in initialize.php, then, try putting

```
require_once '../../includes/initialize.php';
```

within your logoutlink.php

Comment: Yes, $Session is a user defined object. I tried your suggestion and it did not work.